# Controller function for prefixed route group root

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a routes group for admin, with the admin prefix, but I can't reach the '/' route, and I want to use a login controller for admin/, the root of the group prefix. But I get Forbidden error

```
<?
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'namespace' => 'Admin'
], function () {

    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        return view("admin.layout");
    });

    Route::get('users', function ()    {
        return view("admin.layout");
    });
});
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was because I had an "admin" folder in the public path and It was going to the real dir instead of the virtual friendly url.